# Downloading/Saving HTML embedded PDF with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a page with embedded PDF.

```
<object data="/files/documents/somepdf.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

The embedded PDF has a form that user can edit.

[image]

This PDF view has a button (top right save/print icon) that allows user to download edited document.

**Question** - is there a way to manually download or save edited PDF with JavaScript?

My goal is for user to be able to click on "Submit" button and it takes the filled out form and sends it to some API end point in my system.

Comment: If the embedded pdf editor is an iframe you can interact with it in javascript by refering to iframe elements. Or look for you embedded pdf plugin if has some api to interact with it

Comment: Without knowing the embedded pdf editor and how it is managed on client it's pretty hard to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question - is there a way to manually download or save edited PDF with JavaScript?

That's a loaded question, As with ALL PDFs the Form has been downloaded into the users browser or external pdf viewer, so no your JavaScript cannot touch it, see the downloaded address at the top.
[image]

The other implied question is can the file be saved after edit by the user clicking the icon, and that answer is perhaps. See the Adobe banner when a user attempts to edit the restricted form.

[image]

Thus the user must print the form with handwritten entries and signature, then mail it using their choice of US snail mail or web mail provider.

***It also depends very much on which Browser and form they are using since here the user Fred has printed some entries and thus can continue another time after going bowling***

[image]

Note the forms layout has changed overtime. :-) and the wrong surname that needs re-edit later.

[image]